# Using list comprehension within lambda function?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe with a list of n-gram tuples. I want to convert the list of tuples to list of strings. To do this, I am trying to use list comprehension within my lambda function. However, I keep getting an error saying that my list isn't defined.

```
id     n_grams
 1     [(thanks), (thanks, past), (thanks, past, blue)]
 2     [(support), (support, arm), (support, arm, brace), (support, arm, brace, left)]
 3     [(blue), (blue, sky), (blue, sky, rain)]
 4     [(breaking), (breaking, news), (breaking, news, fire), (breaking, news, fire, aparment)]
```

I am trying to get:

```
id     n_grams
 1     ["thanks", "thanks past", "thanks past blue"]
 2     ["support", "support arm", "support arm brace", "support arm brace left"]
 3     ["blue", "blue sky", "blue sky rain"]
 4     ["breaking", "breaking news", "breaking news fire", "breaking news fire apartment"]
```

I have tried:

```
data['n_grams'] = data.n_grams.apply(lambda row: " ".join(x) for x in row)
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

Comment: `lambda row: [" ".join(x) for x in row]` maybe?

Comment: I feel dumb, that's exactly what it needed. Thanks!

Comment: You mean `.apply(lambda row: " ".join(x for x in row))` note, that is a generator expression, but it is *totally pointless*, it doesn't do anything. So just `.apply(" ".join)` would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by rdas, the solution was simply using hard brackets:

```
data['n_grams'] = data.n_grams.apply(lambda row: [" ".join(x) for x in row])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
df.n_grams.apply(lambda row: [" ".join(x) for x in row])
```